# Unity 3D - Animation works manually but doesn't work with animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

The animation runs in the animator but its not being applied to the GameObject. if i run the animation manually it works fine:
[image]

from the animation itself:
[image]

Comment: That's not a very PG game is it?

Comment: Idk what's is pg?

Comment: it will be probably an M since i wanted to make something similar to Metro

Comment: What happen when you unclicked Apply Root Motion?

Comment: Same problem. I Deleted both the animator and the animation and remade them and it seems to work for now. as for the name of the project it totally unrelated to the game